# Get values from one WinForm textboxes to a class

Tags: c#, winforms

In `Form1` i have `Textbox1`, `Textbox2` and `Textbox3`.
Can someone do example for me to solve: Get values of `Textbox1` and `Textbox2` into  `class1` and print that values to `Textbox3`?

Comment: make Textbox1 and Textbox2 as public. and call it from Form1

Comment: Sorry, im new at c# and I  tried but not work. @Arphile

Comment: What have you tried and what error are you getting @Savanrof ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make texboxes `Modifiers` property in the designer as `public` or `internal`, or add getters and setter:

```
public string GetTextbox1Text()
{
  return Textbox1.Text;
}

public string GetTextbox2Text()
{
  return Textbox2.Text;
}

public string SetTextbox3Text(string textNew)
{
  Textbox3.Text = textNew;
}
```

```
public class Class1
{
  public void Process(Form1 form)
  {
    string str = form.GetTextbox1Text() + ", " + form.GetTextbox2Text();
    form.SetTextbox3Text(str)
  }
}
```

Adapt to what you need.